# javascript code limited by text position in the html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to use this Fireworks javascript. But when i write some text in the middle of the HTML page, the fireworks will not go over it and is limited by the text position...how can i override this and keep the fireworks go up to the top of the page ?
i tryed to fix the SCREEN_WIDTH and SCREEN_HEIGHT position but it doesn't work...

```js
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
    mousePos = {
        x: 400,
        y: 300
    },

    // create canvas
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    particles = [],
    rockets = [],
    MAX_PARTICLES = 400,
    colorCode = 0;

// init
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvas.width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    canvas.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    setInterval(launch, 800);
    setInterval(loop, 1000 / 50);
});

// update mouse position
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mousePos = {
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY
    };
});

// launch more rockets!!!
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        launchFrom(Math.random() * SCREEN_WIDTH * 2 / 3 + SCREEN_WIDTH / 6);
    }
});

function launch() {
    launchFrom(mousePos.x);
}

function launchFrom(x) {
    if (rockets.length < 10) {
        var rocket = new Rocket(x);
        rocket.explosionColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360 / 10) * 10;
        rocket.vel.y = Math.random() * -3 - 4;
        rocket.vel.x = Math.random() * 6 - 3;
        rocket.size = 8;
        rocket.shrink = 0.999;
        rocket.gravity = 0.01;
        rockets.push(rocket);
    }
}

function loop() {
    // update screen size
    if (SCREEN_WIDTH != window.innerWidth) {
        canvas.width = SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    }
    if (SCREEN_HEIGHT != window.innerHeight) {
        canvas.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    }

    // clear canvas
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    var existingRockets = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < rockets.length; i++) {
        // update and render
        rockets[i].update();
        rockets[i].render(context);

        // calculate distance with Pythagoras
        var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mousePos.x - rockets[i].pos.x, 2) + Math.pow(mousePos.y - rockets[i].pos.y, 2));

        // random chance of 1% if rockets is above the middle
        var randomChance = rockets[i].pos.y < (SCREEN_HEIGHT * 2 / 3) ? (Math.random() * 100 <= 1) : false;

/* Explosion rules
             - 80% of screen
            - going down
            - close to the mouse
            - 1% chance of random explosion
        */
        if (rockets[i].pos.y < SCREEN_HEIGHT / 5 || rockets[i].vel.y >= 0 || distance < 50 || randomChance) {
            rockets[i].explode();
        } else {
            existingRockets.push(rockets[i]);
        }
    }

    rockets = existingRockets;

    var existingParticles = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        particles[i].update();

        // render and save particles that can be rendered
        if (particles[i].exists()) {
            particles[i].render(context);
            existingParticles.push(particles[i]);
        }
    }

    // update array with existing particles - old particles should be garbage collected
    particles = existingParticles;

    while (particles.length > MAX_PARTICLES) {
        particles.shift();
    }
}

function Particle(pos) {
    this.pos = {
        x: pos ? pos.x : 0,
        y: pos ? pos.y : 0
    };
    this.vel = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    this.shrink = .97;
    this.size = 2;

    this.resistance = 1;
    this.gravity = 0;

    this.flick = false;

    this.alpha = 1;
    this.fade = 0;
    this.color = 0;
}

Particle.prototype.update = function() {
    // apply resistance
    this.vel.x *= this.resistance;
    this.vel.y *= this.resistance;

    // gravity down
    this.vel.y += this.gravity;

    // update position based on speed
    this.pos.x += this.vel.x;
    this.pos.y += this.vel.y;

    // shrink
    this.size *= this.shrink;

    // fade out
    this.alpha -= this.fade;
};

Particle.prototype.render = function(c) {
    if (!this.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    c.save();

    c.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';

    var x = this.pos.x,
        y = this.pos.y,
        r = this.size / 2;

    var gradient = c.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0.1, x, y, r);
    gradient.addColorStop(0.1, "rgba(255,255,255," + this.alpha + ")");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.8, "hsla(" + this.color + ", 100%, 50%, " + this.alpha + ")");
    gradient.addColorStop(1, "hsla(" + this.color + ", 100%, 50%, 0.1)");

    c.fillStyle = gradient;

    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.flick ? Math.random() * this.size : this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    c.closePath();
    c.fill();

    c.restore();
};

Particle.prototype.exists = function() {
    return this.alpha >= 0.1 && this.size >= 1;
};

function Rocket(x) {
    Particle.apply(this, [{
        x: x,
        y: SCREEN_HEIGHT}]);

    this.explosionColor = 0;
}

Rocket.prototype = new Particle();
Rocket.prototype.constructor = Rocket;

Rocket.prototype.explode = function() {
    var count = Math.random() * 10 + 80;

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var particle = new Particle(this.pos);
        var angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;

        // emulate 3D effect by using cosine and put more particles in the middle
        var speed = Math.cos(Math.random() * Math.PI / 2) * 15;

        particle.vel.x = Math.cos(angle) * speed;
        particle.vel.y = Math.sin(angle) * speed;

        particle.size = 10;

        particle.gravity = 0.2;
        particle.resistance = 0.92;
        particle.shrink = Math.random() * 0.05 + 0.93;

        particle.flick = true;
        particle.color = this.explosionColor;

        particles.push(particle);
    }
};

Rocket.prototype.render = function(c) {
    if (!this.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    c.save();

    c.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';

    var x = this.pos.x,
        y = this.pos.y,
        r = this.size / 2;

    var gradient = c.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0.1, x, y, r);
    gradient.addColorStop(0.1, "rgba(255, 255, 255 ," + this.alpha + ")");
    gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0, 0, 0, " + this.alpha + ")");

    c.fillStyle = gradient;

    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.flick ? Math.random() * this.size / 2 + this.size / 2 : this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    c.closePath();
    c.fill();

    c.restore();
};
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Fireworks!</title>
    </head>
    <body/>
</html>
```

Comment: this fireworks was found here : https://jsfiddle.net/dtrooper/AceJJ/

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/AceJJ/4244/

Comment: It is hard to debug the entire code .Please specify which part is not work and what is the expected result

Comment: @siphalor your jsfiddle is working as expected, but what did you change exactly ?

Comment: haaa, if i add an image, the fireworks go behind it, the picture stay in the foreground...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the canvas used by the script is positioned relative by default. To make it always visible completely on screen we have to make it `fixed` and set the `top` and `left` CSS values to `0`.

Now because its fixed the canvas renders on top of everything. To get it in the background set `z-index` to `-1`.

**All additions together:**

```
canvas.style.position="fixed";
canvas.style.top="0";
canvas.style.left="0";
canvas.style.zIndex="-1";
```

**Complete Source:**

```js
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
  SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
  mousePos = {
    x: 400,
    y: 300
  },

  // create canvas
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  particles = [],
  rockets = [],
  MAX_PARTICLES = 400,
  colorCode = 0;

// init
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  canvas.width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
  canvas.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
  canvas.style.position = "fixed";
  canvas.style.top = "0";
  canvas.style.left = "0";
  canvas.style.zIndex = "-1";
  setInterval(launch, 800);
  setInterval(loop, 1000 / 50);
});

// update mouse position
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  mousePos = {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
  };
});

// launch more rockets!!!
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    launchFrom(Math.random() * SCREEN_WIDTH * 2 / 3 + SCREEN_WIDTH / 6);
  }
});

function launch() {
  launchFrom(mousePos.x);
}

function launchFrom(x) {
  if (rockets.length < 10) {
    var rocket = new Rocket(x);
    rocket.explosionColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360 / 10) * 10;
    rocket.vel.y = Math.random() * -3 - 4;
    rocket.vel.x = Math.random() * 6 - 3;
    rocket.size = 8;
    rocket.shrink = 0.999;
    rocket.gravity = 0.01;
    rockets.push(rocket);
  }
}

function loop() {
  // update screen size
  if (SCREEN_WIDTH != window.innerWidth) {
    canvas.width = SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
  }
  if (SCREEN_HEIGHT != window.innerHeight) {
    canvas.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
  }

  // clear canvas
  context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

  var existingRockets = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < rockets.length; i++) {
    // update and render
    rockets[i].update();
    rockets[i].render(context);

    // calculate distance with Pythagoras
    var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mousePos.x - rockets[i].pos.x, 2) + Math.pow(mousePos.y - rockets[i].pos.y, 2));

    // random chance of 1% if rockets is above the middle
    var randomChance = rockets[i].pos.y < (SCREEN_HEIGHT * 2 / 3) ? (Math.random() * 100 <= 1) : false;

    /* Explosion rules
                 - 80% of screen
                - going down
                - close to the mouse
                - 1% chance of random explosion
            */
    if (rockets[i].pos.y < SCREEN_HEIGHT / 5 || rockets[i].vel.y >= 0 || distance < 50 || randomChance) {
      rockets[i].explode();
    } else {
      existingRockets.push(rockets[i]);
    }
  }

  rockets = existingRockets;

  var existingParticles = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    particles[i].update();

    // render and save particles that can be rendered
    if (particles[i].exists()) {
      particles[i].render(context);
      existingParticles.push(particles[i]);
    }
  }

  // update array with existing particles - old particles should be garbage collected
  particles = existingParticles;

  while (particles.length > MAX_PARTICLES) {
    particles.shift();
  }
}

function Particle(pos) {
  this.pos = {
    x: pos ? pos.x : 0,
    y: pos ? pos.y : 0
  };
  this.vel = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
  this.shrink = .97;
  this.size = 2;

  this.resistance = 1;
  this.gravity = 0;

  this.flick = false;

  this.alpha = 1;
  this.fade = 0;
  this.color = 0;
}

Particle.prototype.update = function() {
  // apply resistance
  this.vel.x *= this.resistance;
  this.vel.y *= this.resistance;

  // gravity down
  this.vel.y += this.gravity;

  // update position based on speed
  this.pos.x += this.vel.x;
  this.pos.y += this.vel.y;

  // shrink
  this.size *= this.shrink;

  // fade out
  this.alpha -= this.fade;
};

Particle.prototype.render = function(c) {
  if (!this.exists()) {
    return;
  }

  c.save();

  c.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';

  var x = this.pos.x,
    y = this.pos.y,
    r = this.size / 2;

  var gradient = c.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0.1, x, y, r);
  gradient.addColorStop(0.1, "rgba(255,255,255," + this.alpha + ")");
  gradient.addColorStop(0.8, "hsla(" + this.color + ", 100%, 50%, " + this.alpha + ")");
  gradient.addColorStop(1, "hsla(" + this.color + ", 100%, 50%, 0.1)");

  c.fillStyle = gradient;

  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.flick ? Math.random() * this.size : this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  c.closePath();
  c.fill();

  c.restore();
};

Particle.prototype.exists = function() {
  return this.alpha >= 0.1 && this.size >= 1;
};

function Rocket(x) {
  Particle.apply(this, [{
    x: x,
    y: SCREEN_HEIGHT
  }]);

  this.explosionColor = 0;
}

Rocket.prototype = new Particle();
Rocket.prototype.constructor = Rocket;

Rocket.prototype.explode = function() {
  var count = Math.random() * 10 + 80;

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var particle = new Particle(this.pos);
    var angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;

    // emulate 3D effect by using cosine and put more particles in the middle
    var speed = Math.cos(Math.random() * Math.PI / 2) * 15;

    particle.vel.x = Math.cos(angle) * speed;
    particle.vel.y = Math.sin(angle) * speed;

    particle.size = 10;

    particle.gravity = 0.2;
    particle.resistance = 0.92;
    particle.shrink = Math.random() * 0.05 + 0.93;

    particle.flick = true;
    particle.color = this.explosionColor;

    particles.push(particle);
  }
};

Rocket.prototype.render = function(c) {
  if (!this.exists()) {
    return;
  }

  c.save();

  c.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';

  var x = this.pos.x,
    y = this.pos.y,
    r = this.size / 2;

  var gradient = c.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0.1, x, y, r);
  gradient.addColorStop(0.1, "rgba(255, 255, 255 ," + this.alpha + ")");
  gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0, 0, 0, " + this.alpha + ")");

  c.fillStyle = gradient;

  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.flick ? Math.random() * this.size / 2 + this.size / 2 : this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  c.closePath();
  c.fill();

  c.restore();
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Fireworks!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    test
  </p>
  <br />
  <p>
    test2
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your solution works perfect, except when we use a picture instead of a text, the fireworks go behind the picture and not over it...any solution for that ? i tried to change the zindex value in the canvas, and/or add lower zindex to the image but it doesn't work...

Comment: Is it necessary that the image should be behind the fireworks? Couldn't you just set `display: none` for the image? ;)

Comment: if the fireworks goes behind the image then we don't see it ;)